# Flip/Reflect Bullet Physics Collider

Tags: c++, game-physics, bulletphysics

I am implementing a system in which I construct furniture meshes out of furniture components. I am trying to make a compound Bullet collider for the combined furniture mesh by creating a box collider for each component and adding them together. In some cases components are scaled by a negative value which means the meshes are flipped. I tried using setLocalScaling on the btCompoundShape but this fails an assert. Is there any way to accomplish this?